# Export user created function output to pdf

Tags: python, plotly

I have a long function that has multiple strings and HTML graphs (using Plotly) in it. I was wondering if it was possible to export it's output to a pdf as an email report programmatically. Here is an example of what the function looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

x = np.random.randn(2000)
y = np.random.randn(2000)

def function():
    print('this is a string')
    iplot([go.Histogram2dContour(x=x, y=y, contours=dict(coloring='heatmap')),
       go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='markers', marker=dict(color='white', size=3, opacity=0.3))], show_link=False)
```

Since the function contains a string and an HTML graph, python stores it as 'nonetype' and thus, my usual workaround to this using PDFkit `from_string` does not work in this case.

Anyone know any way I can download function()'s output to pdf programmatically?

Comment: https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/ ?

Comment: @AMC I got Orca working but this method doesn't accept functions.